# page/2/ Pagination Blank Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Been trying hours now to get pagination to work. Im showing 10 posts/page but when i click Next Page, I constantly get brought to a blank page.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

```
global $wp_query;
$paged = (empty($wp_query->query_vars["paged"])) ? 1 : $wp_query->query_vars["paged"];  //used for paging, eg 10 results on first page, 10 on second

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'jobs',
    's' => $_POST['keyword'],
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => $relation,
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job-type',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $job_type,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $location,
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);


    if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
        $wp_query->the_post();
```

.
.

```
       <?php endwhile;
  <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link('Next Page >>'); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_posts_link('<< Previous        Page'); ?>
```

Comment: My guess is this: `$_POST['keyword']`. How are you passing that variable to subsequent pages?